# How to overcome the failure of data wipe? My smartphone's type is Huawei g730 - U 10

Tags: recovery-mode, data-recovery, huawei

My mobile was restarting several times even when I touch the screen or trying to make a call...then I found this message:

Encryption unsuccessful Encryption was interrupted and can't complete.As a result, the data on your phone is no longer accessible

To resume using your phone, you must perform a factory reset. When you set up your phone after the reset, you'll have an opportunity to restore any data that was backed up to your Google Account.

There is such like a button entitled "Reset phone". When I press it, the phone restarts and enters in "Android system recovery <3e>"

There are more than a category or alternatives to choose from. When I choose the "wipe cache partition", everything is ok and this process completes successfully. On the other hand, When I choose the category of "wipe data/factory reset", unfortunately appears to me this phrase: "wipe data failed".

What should I do? Give me a hand, please!

Answer (score 1):

Common issue with Huawei devices. This happens when the memory chip (eMMC) is damaged and become read-only. 
This is a hardware failure, the only fix is replacing the chip or changing the motherboard. Sometimes heating the chip can solve (temporarily) the issue.

To be sure the eMMC is damaged, power off the phone, **hold volume up and volume down** at the same time then **briefly hit the power button**: if the screen goes purple or you get a more explicit message : Update exception. EMMC is readonly, you can't update your system - the chip is damaged. Otherwise you can flash the device to solve the issue.